# How to pass Sphere as parameter to script in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created several Sphere objects and added them to my scene in Unity3d. Now I need to pass these objects to my script and work with those objects. **How do I do that?** For example when I need to pass Terrain object to the script I would write...

```
public class A: MonoBehaviour {
    public Terrain terrain;
    void Start () {
        terrain = terrain.GetComponent<Terrain>();
    }
    .....
}
```

... and this would work but I can't write:

```
 public class A: MonoBehaviour {
    public Sphere sphere;
    void Start () {
        sphere = sphere.GetComponent<Sphere>();
    }
    .....
}
```

because there is no such type as Sphere (right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GameObject (which is the type of most of the scene objects) instead of Sphere as your reference type.

See also http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameObjects.html on what GameObjects are.

Comment: I knew I could do that but I think I would lose a lot of functionality if I would write `public GameObject sphere`. I mean how then I will be able to change lets say radius of the sphere?

Comment: If you are talking about the PrimitiveType Sphere, all you do is change the localScale of your GameObject. When changing the radius in the Editor, this is exactly what Unity does.

If you really need to access members of a component, you can get that component using anyObject.GetComponent<ComponentType>(). Sphere itself however is no Component, it's only an identifier to select a mesh.

Comment: I get error because of NULL. This is how everything is linked in the editor (objects under Wind are spheres) http://prntscr.com/9j6nrn . In the script all shperes are set with lines like this `center = center.GetComponent<GameObject> ();`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ... continuing. After each shpere is set I am trying to create a custom object which holds all of the spheres and that is where I get NULL. I even added if statement to check if `center` is null and print "NULL" to the console.

Comment: Going away now, will let you know if I fixed it

Comment: Once your objects are assigned using the Editor, you can immediately use the references. You don't need that code that you have in your Start() function, this actually has no effect at all.

Comment: GameObject is not a component, it is a container for components, so you can not get it using GetComponent<GameObject>().